# npm install private github repo github actions

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, github-actions

I have a nodejs project that uses a private git repo as one of it's dependencies. It's defined in package.json like this:

`"repo name": "git+https://{access_token}@github.com/{owner}/{repo name}.git#master"`

My workflow file looks like this:

```yaml
name: Tests

on: [push]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
      - name: Install modules
        run: npm ci
      - name: Run tests
        run: npm test
```

`npm ci` however fails with `npm ERR! remote: Repository not found.`

Using `npm ci` on my local machine and on a clean ubuntu test machine works perfectly when I test it. I can't figure out what's causing this issue when on github actions.

I've read through many other forms but can't find any solution that works or is applicable to my situation. If you have any ideas as to what may be causing this I'd be happy to hear your leads.

Comment: Is the `{access_token}` hard-coded? If not, how is it replaced? Can you fetch the repository on your machine using that access token?

Comment: @rethab for now, it is hard coded. I can fetch that repo on my machine with that access token

Comment: Two things I would try: 1) reproduce locally: try cleaning the npm cache? 2) might it confuse the token used for `actions/checkout` with the one to access the dependency? try `persist-credentials: false`

Comment: @rethab I tried those two things and it worked! Looks like the persist-credentials is all I needed. If you put that up as an answer I'll be sure to mark it as correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The auth token from `actions/checkout` is persisted. Therefore, it might be used again when fetching your npm dependency from GitHub, which doesn't work.

You can opt-out by passing the input `persist-credentials` like so:

```yaml
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      persist-credentials: false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add [this](https://github.com/webfactory/ssh-agent) action after your checkout step and GitHub can access your private repo dependancy. But you should change your package name in package.json like below

```json
"some_package": "git+ssh://git@github.com:<Org_Name>/<Repo_Name>.git#<Branch_name>"
```

Make sure to add a server's private key as a secret, public key to GitHub SSH keys.

Comment: Good alternative, I'll keep that in my back pocket and migrate to it eventually probably. For now though the repository is actually one I do not own and the access token is someone else's so I can't generate an ssh key for it.